# Developing for Excel old version

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, backwards-compatibility

I have installed Office 2010 on my computer, and I'm going to develope a C# application that generates Excel workbooks.
I have Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library, but my client has Office 2003 installed.
I think I need Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library. How can I solve that?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to save the files as `*.xls`, it should be working then. The `14.0` library should be ok.

Comment: theoretically you can develop for 2010 and your clients can open files created for newer version of excel this way: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/924074/how-to-open-new-file-formats-in-earlier-versions-of-microsoft-office